# Fancyhdr header and footer size and font

Tags: fonts, formatting, fancyhdr, size

I am having a hard time formatting fancyhdr's header and footer.
I have tried \small or \fontsize{6}{6}... I can't change it.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}


% **************************
% Taille de la page et marges
% **************************

\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}


% **************************
% En-têtes et pieds de page
% **************************

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\fancyhead[LO]{ \textsc{\Subsubsectionname}}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}

\fancyfoot[LO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\fontsize{6}{6} \thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE]{}



% **************************
% Alignement du headerfooter
% **************************

\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{0mm}
\addtolength\headwidth{2\FHoffset}
\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}
\newlength\FHleft
\newlength\FHright
\setlength\FHright{19mm}

\newbox\FHline
\setbox\FHline=\hbox{\hsize=\paperwidth%
\hspace*{\FHleft}%
\rule{\dimexpr\headwidth-\FHleft-\FHright\relax}{\headrulewidth}\hspace*{\FHright}%
}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-.7\baselineskip\copy\FHline}


% Font formatting packages

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance !

Comment: From the proposed duplicate: you need to add `\selectfont` after setting the size with `\fontsize`. Besides `\small` you could also try `\scriptsize` or `\tiny`.

Comment: Working with \selectfont ! It thaught it was a command to change the font without any link to the size. Thank you all for your help !

Comment: I wonder why you don't use the `\leftmark`. This `\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}` seems like a bit of a hack (and `\gdef` would probably be better here). P.S.: `\leftmark` is higher level than `\rightmark`, so you could use the `\leftmark` instead of the `\rightmark`, and the `\rightmark` instead of the hack, I think.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will try this soon !